# Upload Csv File Content using Axios Post Method React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, papaparse, csvreader

I am trying to upload csv file content i have a api that read csv file header by A .....AZ using form but i need to upload csv file content not csv file i am trying to do it but i failed i tried csv.parse and papa parse ,Here is my code so far i tried please help me where is my error.please help that i can only upload file content in csv not file details .

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { CsvToHtmlTable } from "react-csv-to-table";
import ReactFileReader from "react-file-reader";
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import config from "../Main";
import axios from "axios";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import cross from "../../img/Cross.png";
import Papa from "papaparse";
import csv from "csv";
import { CSVReader } from "react-papaparse";

let authToken = localStorage.getItem("Token");

class Import extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cost_type: null,
      invoice_number: "",
      csv: ", // this is where i need to upload csv file content
      mapping: {
        date: "",
        car: "",
        car_vin: "",
        car_plate_number: "",
        car_mileage: "",
        value: "",
        invoice_number: "",
        cost_type: "",
        description: "",
        net_value: "",
        quantity: ""
      },
      start_row: null,
      label: []
    };
    this.fileInput = React.createRef();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

  }


  handleImportOffer = () => {
    this.fileInput.current.click();
  };

  async handleChange1(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    await this.setState({
      mapping: {
        ...this.state.mapping,
        [name]: value.toUpperCase()
      }
    });
    console.log(this.state.mapping);
  }

  async onChange(event) {
    await this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    }
  }
 onChange1(e) {
    this.setState({ csv: e.target.files[0] });
    console.log("Csv File", this.state.csv);
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem("Token");


    // Here i was trying to read file content and upload it
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      csv.parse(reader.result, (err, data) => {
        var userList = [];
        const csv = data;
        const newUser = {
          csv: csv
        };
        userList.push(newUser);
      });
    };

    const data = {
      cost_type: this.state.cost_type,
      invoice_number: this.state.invoice_number,
      csv: this.state.csv, //and in this i wanted to upload content of the file 
      mapping: { ...this.state.mapping },
      start_row: this.state.start_row
    };



    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `https://digitalfleet.eu/api/1/costs/upload/`,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        Authorization: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(authToken)
      },
      data
    })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          cost_type: null,
          invoice_number: "",
          csv: "",
          mapping: {
            date: "",
            car: "",
            car_vin: "",
            car_plate_number: "",
            car_mileage: "",
            value: "",
            invoice_number: "",
            cost_type: "",
            description: "",
            net_value: "",
            quantity: ""
          },
          start_row: null
        });

        Swal.fire({
          title: "Cost Added",
          type: "success",
          text: "Cost Added Successfully on database !",
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 2000
        });

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Cost Added",
          type: "error",
          text:
            "Error While adding cost please check type correct input value !!",
          timer: 3000
        });

      });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    // const reader = new FileReader();
    this.setState({
      csv: event.target.files[0]
    });
    // reader.readAsBinaryString(csv);
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  };





  render() {

    const { t } = this.props;
    const {
      label

    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div id="invoice" className="modal">
          <a
            href="# "
            rel="modal:close"
            className="float-right text-white h4"
            style={{ marginBottom: "90px" }}
          >
            <img src={cross} alt="Cross" style={{ height: "0.7em" }} />
          </a>
          <p className="mod" style={{ marginTop: "40px" }}>
            {t("importInvoice")}
          </p>
          <hr></hr>
          <form
            noValidate
            autoComplete="off"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            style={{}}
          >
            <div classNam="import_invoice">
              <div className="form-group" style={{ marginTop: "15px" }}>
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" id="ppp">
                  {t("cost_type").toUpperCase()}
                </label>
                <select
                  name="cost_type"
                  value={this.state.cost_type}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  class="form-control donn"
                  style={{ width: "300px", marginTop: "10px" }}
                >
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>
                    {t("choose")}
                  </option>
                  {label.map((c, i) => (
                    <option value={c.value} key={i}>
                      {c.display_name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>

              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <div className="form-group" style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}>
                    <p id="ppp">{t("import_cost_file")}</p>
                    {/* <p id="pp">{t("file_size")}</p> */}

                    {/* <ReactFileReader
                      multipleFiles={false}
                      fileTypes={[".csv"]}
                      handleFiles={this.handleFiles}
                    >
                      <button className="btn" id="bttn">
                        {t("import_cost_file").toUpperCase()}
                        <span className="float-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>
                        </span>
                      </button>
                    </ReactFileReader> */}

                    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                      <button class="btn112" style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}>
                        {t("select_file").toUpperCase()}
                      </button>
                      <input
                        type="file"
                        name="csv"
                        //value={this.state.csv}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}

                        //onChange={this.onChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-4" style={{ marginTop: "65px" }}>
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("import_data_from_row").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    style={{ marginTop: "6px" }}
                    type="number"
                    min={1}
                    value={this.state.start_row}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    name="start_row"
                  />
                </div>

                {this.state.cost_type === "fuel-card" && (
                  <div className="col-sm-4" style={{ marginTop: "65px" }}>
                    <label
                      for="exampleInputEmail1"
                      className="font-weight-bold h6"
                      style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                    >
                      {t("invoice_number").toUpperCase()}
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder={t("type")}
                      name="invoice_number"
                      value={this.state.invoice_number}
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>

              <p className=" " id="ppp">
                {t("select_columns").toUpperCase()}
              </p>
              <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: "25px" }}>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("date").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    maxLength={2}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="date"
                    value={this.state.mapping.date}
                    // value={
                    //   this.state.invoice_type === "fuel-card"
                    //     ? `${date1}`
                    //     : `${this.state.date}`
                    // }

                    onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                    class="form-control donn"
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="col-sm-4">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("plate_number").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    maxLength={2}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="car_plate_number"
                    value={this.state.mapping.car_plate_number}
                    // value={
                    //   this.state.invoice_type === "fuel-card"
                    //     ? `${plate_number1}`
                    //     : `${this.state.plate_number}`
                    // }
                    // value={this.state.plate_number}
                    onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="col-sm-2">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("vin").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    maxLength={2}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="car_vin"
                    value={this.state.mapping.car_vin}
                    onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>

                {this.state.cost_type === "fuel-card" ? (
                  <p></p>
                ) : (
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <label
                      for="exampleInputEmail1"
                      className="font-weight-bold h6"
                      style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                    >
                      {t("invoice_number").toUpperCase()}
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder={t("type")}
                      maxLength={2}
                      className="form-control"
                      name="invoice_number"
                      value={this.state.mapping.invoice_number}
                      onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>

              <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: "25px" }}>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("description").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    maxLength={2}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="description"
                    value={this.state.mapping.description}
                    onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("quantity").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    maxLength={2}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="quantity"
                    value={this.state.mapping.quantity}
                    onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("price_netto_import").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    maxLength={2}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="net_value"
                    value={this.state.mapping.net_value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    className="font-weight-bold h6"
                    style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}
                  >
                    {t("price_brutto_import").toUpperCase()}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={t("type")}
                    maxLength={2}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="value"
                    value={this.state.mapping.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange1.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
                <center>
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    value="Add Invoice"
                    style={{ background: "#b71c1c", color: "white" }}
                    className="btn btn-danger br"
                  >
                    {t("import_invoice")}
                  </button>
                </center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>


        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(Import);
```